# Como se implementa uma annotation "preprocessor"?

Tags: java, compilação

Eu aprendi que as Annotations em Java são só uma forma de injetar metainformação no código. Entretanto, eu tenho visto que frameworks e algumas bibliotecas tem annotations que "magicamente" geram código ou definem regras de compilação. Um exemplo qualquer é o projectlombok:

POJO com getters e setters tradicional:

```
public class DataExample {
    private int data;

    public DataExample(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

POJO usando Lombok:

```
public class DataExample {
    @Getter @Setter private int data;

    public DataExample(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

A diferença é que as annotations @Getter e @Setter fazem o Lombok gerar os métodos getters e setters pra você, então se você os invocá-los em outras classes, eles não dão erro de compilação.

Mas é estranho: Os tutoriais e lições de annotations que eu vi só ensinavam a usar annotations para inserir informação.

Como eu crio annotations que gerem código, criem regras de compilação e coisa do tipo?

Comment: Se quer fazer algo como o `Lombok faz`, veja como é feito [no original](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/src/core/lombok/Getter.java)

Comment: Mas é aí que tá: O arquivo da annotation é só uma annotation. Qual a mágica que acontece pra essa annotation gerar código?

Comment: o que quer com essa pergunta? Entender como funciona ou criar uma anotação própria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que o Lombok utiliza um mecanismo conhecido como APT (Annotation Processing Tool). Com isso é possível que os getters e setter sejam gerados ainda em tempo de compilação. Um link interessante sobre isso:

http://blog.caelum.com.br/metaprogramacao-em-java-o-papel-do-apt/